# DiscordJS v14 Guild Members

Tags: discord.js

I am attempting to get the amount of members from a certain guild ID but I don't know how and I've read the docs with little to no information. I'm on discord V14 nodejs 18.0.0

I have tried caching all members that the bot has since it's only one guild but it didn't work. I was trying to put this stat inside of a voice channel so that I may stop bot clutter and get rid of server stats.

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount

Comment: Once you have the guild, fetch the members, because when the bot starts up it doesn't fetch all members (you can imagine how long that would take and how much memory it would use for bots with millions of users). Example: `await guild.members.fetch()`. This will fetch and cache the users so that `guild.members.cache` should have the correct number of members now.

Answer (score 0):

Caching then checking the number of members should work.

Have you enabled the "Guild Members" privileged intent in your Developer Portal and "Guilds" + "Guild Members" intents in your client initialization ?